# compare hand drawn image to saved image

Tags: android, ios, image, draw

I am developing an app (both android and IOS) and one specific feature that I would like to develop is to be able to compare a hand drawn image with a sample image.

For example if the sample image is a 'b' - then the user draws a 'b' on the screen. We want to be able to automatically compare the two and mark it correct or not..

At this time looking to get any suggestions or if you know of any code that can be licensed to make this happen

Comment: Not sure but i think google vision api might be useful https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Comment: Also take a look at OpenCV. It's a general purpose computer vision library that can be used to do a variety of image processing tasks. Be aware, though, that this is a complex, difficult problem.